# beamer template for Miktex 2.9

Tags: beamer

I want a basic beamer-template that works straight with latest version of Miktex 2.9. I just want to be able to run it and have no error messages complaining about missing this and that. I have the packages `xcolor` and `pgf` installed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Sorry, not quite understand your question. Have u searched the beamer tag in this site?  There are plenty of examples to try out, then ask your concerns specifically.

Comment: `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
Hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316242/beamer-with-miktex-2-7 sounds like it would also be from you?). The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: If its just you being annoyed by the error messages, either set Miktex to automatically install missing packages or switch to a "complete" distribution like texlive, which comes with probably all packages you will ever need.

Answer (score 1):

A quik'n'derty template can be generated in TeXstudio for example, utilizing the built-in wizards.

### Prerequisites

1. Install TeXstudio
2. Familiarize with TeXstudio
3. Start up TeXstudio

### Actions

1. After Start goto <kbd>Menu</kbd> -> <kbd>Wizards</kbd> -> <kbd>Quick beamer presentation</kbd>
2. Select the theme you like the most.
3. Select all the packages you need.
4. Add title and author.
5. Check for babel package and select your language.
6. Check for graphicx package.
7. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

The template can now be used for any sort of presentation.

### Result of above steps

You get and can use this quik'n'derty template:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}
    \author{Joanne Doe}
    \title{A smexy title}
    %\subtitle{}
    %\logo{}
    %\institute{}
    %\date{}
    %\subject{}
    %\setbeamercovered{transparent}
    %\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \frame[plain]{\maketitle}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```